# Side-tangle and its solution

Tags: iri-node

I still do not understand the whole side-tangle problem after reading the [article](https://blog.iota.org/coming-soon-iri-1-5-2-52114ca67a70) by Dom. So this side-tangle starts by referencing some milestone and then grows further by adding txs which are only referencing their own sub-tangle txs.

Then it can happen that a walk (initiated by calling getTransactionsToApprove) ends up in this side-tangle (by stepping from that initial milestone from the maintangle into the sidetangle) and consequently has to validate a lot of txs. This consumes a lot of resources and results in the node freezing and getting out of sync. I can fully understand this.

So now v1.5.2 came up with a more sophisticated walk preventing this. But why doesn't the max-depth parameter already (available in versions < v1.5.2) prevent this from happening?

Can somebody explain where my reasoning fails?

Comment: The walk ends up on the side Tangle by landing on a transaction that "stitches" the two tangles together by picking one parent on the main Tangle and one on the side Tangle.  I don't know why max-depth doesn't prevent that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MAX_DEPTH` prevents against malicious `getTransactionsToApprove` calls that give a huge `depth` and therefore create a large "Subtangle" to walk in.

But in this case, a user gives a normal `depth` (e.g. 5), so `MAX_DEPTH` cannot prevent this.

Assume that the current milestone is **M** and the side tangle has been forked off milestone *M-1000*. Also, assume that there is a transaction (we'll call it *stitching transaction*) which approves both a recent transaction of the side tangle (e.g. 1000 transactions after the last milestone) - let's call that transaction **S** - and the milestone *M-3*.

When now starting a random walk [blue] at depth 5 [*M-5*], it may (does not have to) end up at milestone *M-3*. From there, there is a certain chance that it continues walking to the *stitching transaction* **S**. As soon as this happens, the node has to validate that this transaction is indeed valid. Therefore, its both approved transactions have to be validated. Validating *M-3* is simple (it's a milestone), but validating *S* takes a long time, since most of the side tangle [orange] needs to be validated.

The current fix prevents that such transactions **S** or the *stitching transaction* get chosen by the random walk (because the milestone approved by them is *M-1000* and therefore too old).

[image: Tangle]

Comment: Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/BFMGcAN.png) the scenario you described @mihi? May I add the picture to your answer?

Comment: @Zauz pedantic people might notice that there have to be at least two other nodes (milestones) on the path between *M* and *M-3* (being *M-1* and *M-2*), but apart from that it looks fine to me (perhaps you can add *M-4* between *M-3* and *M-5* as well). 

Since this is stackoverflow, feel free to edit my answers with your illustrations. :)

Comment: @Zauz perhaps it is also a good idea to color the transactions of the side tangle that are not (indirectly) approved by S in a slightly different shade of yellow (to emphasize which transactions have to be validated)

Comment: Is a depth 5 random walk starting at M-5 or M-4?

Comment: I did not test it, but the [source code](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/61471338de5209f646f68bd658e6189925362064/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/service/tipselection/impl/EntryPointSelectorImpl.java#L30-L38) looks like it passes M-6 to `findClosestNextMilestone`, which in turn will search for a number strictly greater than M-6 and therefore find M-5.

Comment: Aren’t the blue arrows pointing into the wrong direction if they are meant to illustrate the walk?

Comment: thanks @Zauz for your graphical additions!!! very illustrative!

Comment: @ralf Depends on how you look at it. I'll come up with something...